# How to share a library between ROS 1 and ROS 2?

Tags: ros, ros2, catkin, colcon, cmake

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Does anyone found a solution to share a C++ library (ROS agnostic) between ROS 1 and ROS 2?

There were some discussions about it but I did not found any clear solution.
This use case should be more and more common while organizations are moving to ROS 2 but want to share some code as library in a single repo.

Previous discussion: https://discourse.ros.org/t/software-reuse-in-ros1-and-ros2/2262

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/328239/how-to-share-a-library-between-ros-1-and-ros-2?/) by [rreignier](https://answers.ros.org/users/21983/rreignier/) on ROS Answers with karma: 544 on 2019-07-11

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-07-11**:
Within ROS-Industrial there was also a discussion about this ([this one](https://discourse.ros.org/t/ros2-transition-strategy/9154)). The conclusion so far: make the "common" library a pure cmake package and treat it like a system dependency in both ROS 1 and ROS 2.

---

edit: You even participated in that discussion I just noticed.

**Comment by [rreignier](https://answers.ros.org/users/21983/rreignier/) on 2019-07-11**:
Thank you @gvdhoorn.
Do you have an example of such library?

**Comment by [rreignier](https://answers.ros.org/users/21983/rreignier/) on 2019-07-11**:
Ah, yes, I was looking for that special discussion but did not managed to find it :)

**Comment by [rreignier](https://answers.ros.org/users/21983/rreignier/) on 2019-07-11**:
I have browsed the ros-industriel github but did not found a repo hosting a library that could be used in both ROS 1 and ROS 2.
Do you know if there is one somewhere?

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-07-11**:
I think a public example of this setup would be [opw_kinematics](https://github.com/Jmeyer1292/opw_kinematics) as a shared dependency, with [tesseract](https://github.com/ros-industrial-consortium/tesseract) depending on that. The public version of all that is only ROS 1, but it's also being used in ROS 2 in the same way.

We've not completely made up our minds, but this is most likely the approach we'll take. Whether the two ROS versions will be hosted in a single repository (branches) or in separate repositories has not been decided yet.

Note btw that this idea (treat common functionality as system dependencies) is nothing new, and was (and is!) actually a recommended practice in ROS 1 as well. You just need to make sure to not "contaminate" your ROS-agnostic library with ROS datastructures (ie: using ROS msgs as generic data containers, etc).

**Comment by [rreignier](https://answers.ros.org/users/21983/rreignier/) on 2019-07-11**:
Thanks you. I know that it is the recommended practice to make pure cmake packages but I have hardly seen it in ROS.
And the `package.xml` should contain `<buildtool_depend>catkin</buildtool_depend>` while it is different for ros 2 with ament.

I have not found the use of `opw_kinematics` in `tesseract` is it already in use?

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-07-11**:
`tesseract` is undergoing extensive refactoring right now, so the publicly available code does not yet depend on the pure cmake version of `opw_kinematics`. It might already be available in [ros-industrial-consortium/tesseract#72](https://github.com/ros-industrial-consortium/tesseract/pull/72), but I'm not sure.

> And the `package.xml` should contain `<buildtool_depend>catkin</buildtool_depend>` while it is different for ros 2 with ament.

That is only required if you want to build it as a package in a catkin/colcon workspace. System dependencies do not need that necessarily.

**Comment by [rreignier](https://answers.ros.org/users/21983/rreignier/) on 2019-07-11**:
Ok for tesseract.

> System dependencies do not need that necessarily.

When you say System dependencies, you mean directly installed in /usr/lib or it still can be use in a workspace?

Following `opw_kinematics` example, I think I have managed to make such library. I need to test it further and will report.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

With the help of  @gvdhoorn I have managed to create a demo using a pure CMake library used by both a ROS 1 and a ROS 2 nodes.

https://github.com/romainreignier/share_ros1_ros2_lib_demo

---

Originally posted by [rreignier](https://answers.ros.org/users/21983/rreignier/) with karma: 544 on 2019-07-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1